# Credential Parameter not working for Invoke-sqlcmd

Tags: powershell, invoke-sqlcmd

I am using the Invoke-sqlcmd cmdlet in Powershell to run an SQL query saved in a string against a remote server.

I have included the credential parameter to ask for domain credentials to connect to the SQL instance.

I've tested this without the credential parameter; instead running the Powershell window as the user, this works fine, so I am confident that permissions for the user are set correctly.

However, I cannot get it to work with the credential parameter.

```
Import-Module -Name SqlServer -force

function Correct-Servername {
    param(
        [string] $dataSource = ".\SQL",
        [string] $database = "MASTER",
        [string] $sqlCommand = "sp_dropserver @@servername DECLARE   @ServerName SQL_VARIANT = (SELECT serverproperty('Servername')),   @SQLQuery NVARCHAR(4000); SET @SQLQuery = 'sp_addserver ''' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(100), @SERVERNAME) + ''', ''LOCAL''' PRINT @SQLQuery EXECUTE sp_executesql @SQLQuery"
      )
    $cred = Get-Credential
    Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $sqlCommand -ServerInstance $dataSource -Database $database -Credential $cred

}

Correct-Servername | out-file -FilePath C:\Temp\correct_servername.log
```

This is the error i receive:

```
cmdlet Get-Credential at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
Credential
Invoke-Sqlcmd : Login failed for user 'domain\user'.
At C:\Temp\Rename-Create-Replication-2.ps1:20 char:2
+     Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $sqlCommand -ServerInstance $dataSource -Dat ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExceptionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand

Invoke-Sqlcmd :
At C:\Temp\Rename-Create-Replication-2.ps1:20 char:2
+     Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $sqlCommand -ServerInstance $dataSource -Dat ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], ParserException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExecutionFailureException,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand
```

Any assistance is appreciated.